# unable to search character in a given string using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to find whether the character is present in a given string or not but unable to search and increment value though it is present

```
  Dim testchar,noOfSpecialChar
   noOfSpecialChar=0

Dim specialChars
specialChars="*[@.^$|?#*+!)(_=-]."
 for lngIndex = 1 to Len("test@123")
    testchar = mid("test@123",lngIndex,1)
    if((InStr(specialChars,testchar))) then
        noOfSpecialChar=noOfSpecialChar+1
end if  
next
```

Comment: The code is sound, except `InStr()` returns the character position if one is found where as you are using it as a boolean condition (`True` or `False`). Changing the `If` to `If InStr(specialChars, testchar) > 0 Then` will give you what you are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is `InStr()` as highlighted [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//wybb344c%28v%3dvs.85%29);

> Returns the position of the first occurrence of one string within another.

We can use this knowledge to create a boolean comparison by checking the return value of `InStr()` is greater than 0.

```
Dim testString: testString = "test@123"
Dim testchar, foundChar
Dim noOfSpecialChar: noOfSpecialChar = 0
Dim specialChars: specialChars = "*[@.^$|?#*+!)(_=-]."

For lngIndex = 1 To Len(testString)
  testchar = Mid(testString, lngIndex, 1)
  'Do we find the character in the search string?
  foundChar = (InStr(specialChars, testchar) > 0)
  If foundChar Then noOfSpecialChar = noOfSpecialChar + 1   
Next
```